# A service that returns paged Products with optional filtering

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In order to better understand what the code does, I've captured [this screencast](https://www.screencast.com/t/GltPH3oqPU).

Basically, I have a products page and a user can filter products.

**CODE**

Here is the `Page` action method on my `ProductController`:

```
public ActionResult Page(SearchViewModel search, int page = 1)
{
  var viewModel = _productService.GetPagedProducts(search, page);
  PopulateDropDownSelectListsForSearchVm(viewModel.Search);
  return View(viewModel);
}
```

That `PopulateDropDownSelectListsForSearchVm` is a helper method that sits within the controller.

Here is the implementation of the `GetPagedProducts` method on the `IProductService` interface:

```
public ProductPageViewModel GetPagedProducts(SearchViewModel search, int page = 1)
{
  int totalNumberOfProducts;
  if (HaveSearchTermsChanged(search)) page = 1;
  var products = _context.Products.Where(p => p.IsDeleted == search.ShowDeleted).AsQueryable();
  if (search.CategoryId != 0) products = products.Where(p => p.CategoryId == search.CategoryId);
  if (search.BrandId != 0) products = products.Where(p => p.BrandId == search.BrandId);
  if (search.QualityId != 0) products = products.Where(p => p.QualityId == search.QualityId);

  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search.SearchTerm))
  {
    products = products
                .Where(p => p.Name == search.SearchTerm.Trim())
                .OrderBy(p => p.Name);
    totalNumberOfProducts = products.Count();
    products = products.Skip(_recordsPerPage * (page - 1)).Take(_recordsPerPage);
  }
  else
  {
    products = products.OrderBy(p => p.Name);
    totalNumberOfProducts = products.Count();
    products = products.Skip(_recordsPerPage * (page - 1)).Take(_recordsPerPage);
  }

  var productPageVm = new ProductPageViewModel
  {
    Products = ProductViewModelFactory.BuildListOfProductViewModels(products.ToList()),
    Pagination = new PaginationViewModel
    {
      CurrentPage = page,
      RecordsPerPage = _recordsPerPage,
      TotalRecords = totalNumberOfProducts
    },
    Search = search
  };

  TrackCurrentSearchTerm(productPageVm);
  return productPageVm;
}
```

Readability is really important to me, and right now it just doesn't feel readable. What can I do to improve the overall code, and have it be very readable?

Comment: What aspects of 'readability' are you concerned about. Its looks fine, although there are a few areas where the code could be simplified (for example, `if (HaveSearchTermsChanged(search)) page = 1;` is pointless and you could move your `.OrderBy(p => p.Name);`, `totalNumberOfProducts = products.Count();` and `products = products.Skip(_recordsPerPage * (page - 1)).Take(_recordsPerPage);` lines to after the `if` block and delete the `else` block

Comment: In addition, your checks for the value of the 3 dropownlists (e.g. `if (search.CategoryId != 0)` suggests you not generating them correctly and because the 'label' option should be `null`, not `0`

Comment: Note also you do not need `.AsQueryable()` - it already is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to move the `pagination` settings to your `SearchModel`

Then you can have an utility/extension method or whatever you whish with this signature

```
public IQueryable<Product> ApplyFilter(IQueryable<Product> productQuery, SearchModel model)
```

and you write there ll the filtering business, so you can re use it in more methods and simplify the readability of your main method.

Finally, I would not recommend to rewrite your `if` statements like this

```
if (search.CategoryId != 0)
{
    products = products.Where(p => p.CategoryId == search.CategoryId);
}
```